# Make a key click a certain place on the screen

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I am running a game that has buttons on both sides of the screen, which gives you an easy control on a tablet.  But on ARC it makes it difficult to use because you need to move your mouse across the screen a bunch of times.  Does ARC Welder have an option to make a key on the keyboard "tap" a certain place on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the concept of scripting, you could use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to use keyboard events to click specific areas of the screen. This would be through your OS, not the ARC, but I think the script can be linked to a specific application so it will only run with that app.
See specifically [Click](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm)